# How can I have the contents in my template for Polymer select "all" tags?

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am learning polymer and web components with it and hit a point where I would like to make a custom element that can fetch all tags instead of a specific one. I was thinking if I could use a wildcard character it would work but turns out it doesn't. Is this possible?

```
<div class="card-header" horizontal layout>
    <div id="image_section" flex two>
        <content select="img"></content>
    </div>

    <div id="text_section" flex>
        <content select="*"></content>
    </div>
</div>
```

So then I would be able to use something like below instead of having to predict all possible tags a user could potentially use with my element.

```
<project-preview force_full_size>
    <img width="900" height="350">

    <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

    <some-other-custom-element> 
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2> 
    </some-other-custom-element>
</project-preview>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can juste use :
    <content></content>
It will insert the whole content of your element inside it (if you don't use the select attribute it will inject all children nodes that have not been already inserted in a content with select)

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. If you don't mind, for future reference where did you find that out? Was it the polymer docs or somewhere else?

Comment: @hak8or: it is in the ['Your first Polymer app'](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-2.html) section, step2, about halfway the page. Not sure if it also explained elsewhere.